# An equivalent of : $f(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{(1+t^3)^{1/3}} dt$

Tags: integration

$\forall\ x\ \in\ \left]0,+\infty\right[\ $ we put:
$$
{\rm f}\left(x\right)
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\rm e}^{-xt} \over \left(1 + t^{3}\right)^{1/3}}\,{\rm d}t
$$
The question is the question is to find an equivalent of $\,\,{\rm f}\left(x\right)$ when $x \to 0^{+}$.

That means find a simple function $g$ such that when $x \to 0^+$ we have : $f(x)\sim g(x)$ that means : $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1$$

Comment: What do you mean *an equivalent of $f$*?

Comment: we say $g$ is an equivalent of $f$ when $x \to 0^+$ and write $f \sim g$ when $x \to 0^+$ , if $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$ that means : $g-f=o(f)$ when $x \to 0^+$

Comment: So $f(x)$ is an equivalent of $f(x)$.  If that's too trivial, try $f(x) + 1$.  Well, if you want something more "closed form", try $\ln(1/x)$.

Comment: @ Robert Israel : I mean a simple equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\rm f}\left(x\right)
=
\int_{0}^{\infty}{{\rm e}^{-xt} \over \left(1 + t^{3}\right)^{1/3}}\,{\rm d}t}$

> When $x \gg 1$:
> \begin{align}
> {\rm f}\left(x\right)
> &=
> \int_{0}^{\infty}
> {{\rm e}^{-t} \over x\left[1 + \pars{t/x}^{3}\right]^{1/3}}\,{\rm d}t
> =
> {1 \over x}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}
> \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1/3 \choose n}\bracks{\pars{t \over x}^{3}}^{n}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1/3 \choose n}{1 \over x^{3n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \expo{-t}t^{3n}\,\dd t
> =
> {1 \over x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1/3 \choose n}{\pars{3n}! \over x^{3n}}
> =
> {1 \over x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
> {\Gamma\pars{4/3}\pars{3n}! \over n!\Gamma\pars{4/3 - n}}\,{1 \over x^{3n}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> {1 \over x}\pars{1 + {2 \over x^{3}} + \cdots}
> \end{align}

$$
\mbox{For example, we can take}\ \color{#0000ff}{\large{\rm g}\pars{x} = {1 \over x}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica gives 
$$
\frac{G_{1,4}^{4,1}\left(\frac{s^3}{27}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{2}{3} \\
 0,0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)}{2 \sqrt{3} \pi  \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$ for the integral, and 
expanding this in a power series at $0,$ gets
$$
\frac{-3 \sqrt{3} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \log (s)-2 \sqrt{3} \gamma  \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\sqrt{3} \log (27)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\sqrt{3}
   \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{6 \pi }+\frac{4 \pi ^2 s}{27 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2}+O\left(s^2\right),
$$
so the dominant term is 
$$
\frac{-3 \sqrt{3} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{6\pi} \log (s)
$$

Running FullSimplify on the power series, gets one
$$
\left(-\log (s)+\frac{\pi }{6 \sqrt{3}}-\gamma +\frac{\log
   (3)}{2}\right)+\frac{4 \pi ^2 s}{27 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2}+O\left(s^2\right),
$$
which agrees with Robert Israel's comment.

Comment: Note that this is just $-\log(s)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes, see edit...

Answer (score 0):

Set
$$
h(x,t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\mathrm{e}^{-tx} & \text{if} & t\in[0,1), \\
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-tx}}{t} & \text{if} & t\in [1,\infty),
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and $g(x)=\int_0^\infty h(x,t)\,dt$.